# Android: Get directions from Google Map 

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, direction

I'm trying to give a direction to the user using google map from one location to another. 
I'm using the code bellow but I have no idea why it's not working. I can't figure out the problem everything seems right.

```
final double latitude = 37.894404;
final double longitude = -122.0660386;

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));

                if(lastKnownLocation != null){

                    double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                    double longi = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+lat+","+longi+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));

                    startActivity(intent);

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(contactus.this,"Coudn't get provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }           
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it working and here is the code I used,

```
final double latitude = 45.894404;
final double longitude = -112.0660386;

LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
String towers = lManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
Location userCurrentLocation = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

if(userCurrentLocation != null){

     double lat = userCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
     double longi = userCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

     Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+lat+","+longi+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
     startActivity(intent);

}else{

    Toast.makeText(contactus.this, "Couldn't locate a provider to find your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Don't forget to add the premission to find the user location to you manifest, include it above ,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to wrap your call to LocationManager with a try/catch block and grab whatever exception you're getting off the call. Have a look below. This will make the call and catch the exception.. Go from there once you know why it's coming back NULL. You will always have trouble getting location geopoints using the emulator for whatever reason. Also, Google does not always return with geopoints so in the emulator I have looped until it has come back.. Not a good idea

```
    try{
                 Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                 Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());

                 //Toaster on high-----------------//
                 Context context = getApplicationContext();
                 CharSequence text = "IOException:  " + e.getMessage();
                 int dur = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast.makeText(context, text, dur).show();
```

Comment: I'm actually running this on an actual device. also I tried to give just longitude and latitude instead of current location to the google uri, but it didn't work! so I don't think getting the current location is the issue